# How can I determine what features an auto-encoder cares about?

Tags: pca, deep-learning, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

I am messing around with some stock returns data to compare the performance of a PCA model to that of an autoencoder. Both models are dimension reduction techniques. My returns set is for around 2500 US stocks.

I am fitting a PCA, discarding most of the eigenvectors, then reversing the rotation using just the first 10 eigenvectors.

Separately, I fit an auto-encoder. I reduce the dimensions of each layer from 2500 to 500 to 100 to 10, and then back again. As expected, the results of the PCA modelled returns look very similar to the AEC (autoencoder) modelled returns.

[image: PCA vs AEC]

In the image I include, you can see the performance of 3 models, regular PCA, robust PCA (PCAH), and autoencoder (AEC).

What I want to do now is get a sense of what features of the original returns each model cares about. For the PCA it is easy. I can simply look at the eigenvectors and see which stocks have weights far from zero.

With PCA, typically the first eigenvector has all stocks more or less equally weighted, so this represents "the market". The other eigenvectors start to get interesting. For example, if you see one of the eigenvectors has positive weight in energy stocks but negative weight in tech stocks and mostly zero weight in everything else, you can say that this factor cares about when the energy sector moves in the opposite direction to the tech sector. (I just pulled this example out of thin air, I have not actually looked at the eigenvectors yet).

So here comes the question: How can I do something similar for the auto-encoder? Is there a good way of determining which stocks each of the 10 encoded series in the auto-encoder cares about?

Or to put this another slightly different way: with a PCA, I can use the eigenvectors to determine how to vary the input space to make changes to 1 and only 1 of the series in the reduced space. Is there a way of taking an auto-encoder and determining how to vary the input space, such that 1 and only 1 of the reduced series varies?

Comment: Having thought about this, the only thing I can come up with is to do a sort of deep dream for auto-encoder. Run the model in reverse and see what activates each node in the reduced space. If anything interesting turns up, I'll post it as an answer here.

Comment: The short answer is nobody really knows how to do this for deep networks. Long answer: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01933.pdf. There do exist models which are more transparent, and PCA is one of them. I often use Random Forest to quickly measure feature importance as this is very robust and can detect non-linear and interaction terms. You should probably also take a look at [vector autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) since you are looking at time series. In fact VAR is commonly used in portfolio theory, which seems to be where you're headed.